# how can i get from a character to the UTF 16 equivalent in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I need to create a function that turns characters from a word and adds the UTF 16 value of each character

Is it alright to use .charCodeAt or is there another way?

If this doesn't make a lot of sense please leave a comment and I will elaborate

Comment: charCodeAt should be fine... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `.charCodeAt` for this.

```js
''.length;
//=> 2
```

What?!

```js
''.charCodeAt(0)
//=> 55356

''.charCodeAt(1)
//=> 57135

String.fromCharCode(''.charCodeAt(0))
//=> "�" (broken)

String.fromCharCode(''.charCodeAt(1))
//=> "�" (broken)
```

You need to use a library like [Punycode.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/punycode)

```js
punycode.ucs2.decode('');
//=> [127791]

punycode.ucs2.encode([127791]);
//=> ""
```